# How to install a Debian package from internet?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I am trying to install Debian kernel sources using the following commands -

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

It prompts me to insert the Debian disk to continue the installation.

Why is this so? I have used other Linux Distros and the default behavior seems to be to install from an internet repository.

How should I change the default repository location? i.e. configure online repo for Debian and offline one for Ubuntu?

Comment: Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change the entries to point to some mirror. (See also `man 5 sources.list`)

Comment: @sr_ You mean I need to configure the mirrors manually? But with yum install kernel-devel one doesn't need to do it. What is the difference here?

Comment: @sr_ Alternatively is it possible to use yum as a package manager with Debian?

Comment: No please don't try to do this.  [Ideally, mirror setup is done on install](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.installation-steps.html#idp12006864). That said, [editing `sources.list` is not hard, basic setups require 2 lines (link to the Wiki).](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

Comment: @sr_ Perhaps you should've put in your suggestions as an answer so that I could select it. Or do you think you have too many points already? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik you end up having no mirrors configured in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if you skipped the corresponding questions during system setup. As already pointed out, you just have to edit your `sources.list` file, followed by `apt-get update` to update your local package index.

Comment: why not write an example entry to sources.list that people can just go and use?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and seems like it happens when cdrom repository is above the online repository. When commented `deb cdrom` and ran `apt update` I was able to install the additional packages.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.0.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190706-10:24]/ $

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```